# Vários RDLC (Report Viewer) em um único relatório

Tags: c#, .net, relatório, reportviewer

Tenho um relatório em Report Viewer que é todo injetado via parâmetros, não uso DataSet.

Preciso fazer com que ele imprima um cabeçalho que seria um único modelo de relatório (um arquivo RDLC), o corpo seria outro modelo e se repetiria várias vezes (não dá para fazer como tabela pois ele é todo irregular e assimétrico) e se encerraria com o rodapé.

Existe possibilidade de algo do tipo?

Comment: não é melhor criar vários textbox, em vez de tentar colocar varios rdlc em 1 Report Viewer, ou então utilizar de subreport?

Comment: Vários RDLC acredito que não possa, recomendo também ajustar para trabalhar com Dataset e subreport, do contrário a manutenção acredito que ficará muito complicada.